# how to sum generic numbers in java

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have the following scenario:

```java
class MyListOfNumbers<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
{
    public T sum()
    {
        return list_of_Ts.stream()
        .sum();
    }
}
```

I know nothing (on purpose) about T except it is a number and it can be compared to "siblings" (needed for sorting stuff...).

Obviously this doesn't work and it won't work in an old-Java fashion (ie. loops) because you simply can't, as far as I know, do `T x = 0`.

Neither this will work for I think the same reason and the fact that *T* doesn't implement *sum*; moreover I read it wouldn't work on empty sets.

```java
class MyListOfNumbers<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>
{
    public T sum()
    {
        return list_of_Ts.stream()
        .reduce(0, T::sum);
    }
}
```

Then how to do that?

**EDIT**: please consider T can be anything from Byte to a BigDecimal and forcing it to a integer might mean loosing data

Comment: How are you creating `list_of_Ts`?

Comment: @alayor It actually comes from an HashMap.entrySet()

Comment: @alayor That doesn't really matter. It could be passed via constructor, or created internally and filled with `void add(T e){list_of_Ts.add(e);}` method. What is important is that we can assume that we have access to `List<T> list_of_Ts` which may contain some `T` elements.

Comment: duolicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429030/use-of-java-8-lambdas-with-generics

Answer (score 3):

Pass in an accumulator function and the identity value as parameters:

```
public T sum(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator) {
  return list_of_Ts.stream().reduce(identity, accumulator);
}
```

Note that if you want to avoid having to pass these in when you actually call it, you can create static methods to do the call:

```
public static int intSum(MyListOfNumbers<Integer> list) {
  return list.sum(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
}

public static double doubleSum(MyListOfNumbers<Double> list) {
  return list.sum(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
}

// etc.
```

Comment: Could you expand it a little bit? I don't think I got it. You mean _.reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y)_?